# Is youtube search v3 api type param working well?

Tags: youtube-api

I opened this question because I didn't see similar cases.

I'm working with the youtube search v3 api and there are some queries searching by type `channel` that are returning me some video resources.

This is the params that I'm sending to the API

```
{'q': 'adolfo chaab gustavo', 'type': 'channel', 'maxResults': 50, 'order': 'relevance', 'regionCode': 'AR', 'safeSearch': 'none', 'part': 'id,snippet', 'pageToken': ''}
```

Also, I thought about any bug in my code but if I did the search in the web with the type as channel too. Also, it's returning me the same response.

Can you help me with this case? My first case was **Jun 25, 4:01 AM UTC +1**. Thanks!